# Get class in Python decorator

Tags: python

In this code:

```
def online_only(func, self):
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        if self.running:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return False
    return f

class VM(object):
   @property
   def running(self):
       return True

   @property
   @online_only
   def diskinfo(self):
       return True
```

I want `diskinfo` to run only when `VM.running` returned `True`. How can I get `online_only` to be able to read `self.running`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self` is passed as the first parameter to the wrapping function, so just treat the first parameter specially in `f`:

```
def online_only(func):
    def f(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.running:
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return False
    return f
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can not have two arguments in `def online_only(func, self)` ? it will raise TypeError, so change it to `def online_only(func)`
2. The first argument to wrapped function would be self, you can just use that 
   e.g.

---

```
def online_only(func):
    def f(self):
        if self.running:
            return func(self)
        else:
            return False
    return f

class VM(object):
    @property
    def running(self):
        return True

    @property
    @online_only
    def diskinfo(self):
        return True

print VM().diskinfo
```