# Refer to class variable in another class variable definition

Tags: python

```
class SomeClass:
    SOME_CONST = "hello"
    SOME_OTHER_CONST = SomeClass.SOME_CONST + " world"
```

This doesn't work.

> NameError: name 'SomeClass' is not defined

Is there any way to refer to the class within the class?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need the class name, or do you just need access to the other class attributes?  You treat it as just another variable in the same scope, e.g. `SOME_OTHER_CONST = SOME_CONST`

Comment: This question was asked a few days ago. The short answer is no. The long answer is sometimes using a metaclass or something. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987018/why-does-self-outside-a-functions-parameters-give-a-not-defined-error/9987102#9987102) for an explanation of why.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need the class name

```
class SomeClass:
   SOME_CONST = "hello"
   SOME_OTHER_CONST = SOME_CONST + " world"
```

Comment: @AramKocharyan PHP needs to reference the class to access a class variable because it has a more standard notion of class. In python, the VM enters a local scope and executes all code under the `class` statement as if it were a function. It then turns the resulting name space into the class. So you can do this in Python because it's already in the same name space.

Comment: worth mentioning that order matters here, i.e. `SOME_CONST` cannot be defined after it's dereferenced