# Customizing a Widget for ManyToMany field to a Model that have a circular ForeignKey to itself

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I have two models Category and Products.

- a Product can have multiple Categories
- a Category can have multiple Products.
- Categories have a circular Foreign key, to itself.
- not all Categories have the same depth level

Example:

- Category A

  - Category A_1
  - category A_2

    - Category A_2_1
- Category B
- Category C

  - Category C_1

**`models.py`**

```
class Product:
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Category:
    categories = models.ForeignKey(self)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

As Form I use a ModelForm:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['categories', 'name', 'short_description', 'description']
        widgets = {
            'categories': MyWidget,
        }
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to implement a conditional select (narrow options) On Product Form creation:

1. Only top parent Categories(level 0 A,B,C) are available
2. The user select a parent Category.  If the parent has children a new Select box appear with his children(category level 1 A1,C1)
3. The user select a level 1 Category (A1,C1). If the parent has children a new Select box appear with his children(level 2 A2)

   - The process is repeated until no children are availavable(recursive), an user select the "smallest" category in the tree
   - A new button is available for the user to add more categories and start the 1-3 process again
   - I want to do the select,add new select using JavaScript
   - On Form Submit I want to send only the last children categories

Options I thought:

1. Change the ManyToMany coresponding default Fields - looks like there are no good hooks and/or inheritance
2. Use a non-default custom Field instean of ManytoMany(like Charfield) - more complex on clean,saving Form
3. Change/Inherit the widget. My issues is how to send the data to the default Field on submit, and get/show it on edit

Practical, let's say I have 7 Select Boxes, with the values for each:

1. Parent1->Child11->Child111
2. Parent2->Child21
3. Parent3->Child31->Child311

How do I tell Django on browser submit(with other data) to send to ManyToMany the last Child in all three of them

I can gather them with Javascript, but I have to tell Django get this data, this is what you need.

I need some help as code and indication how to do this.

[image]

Comment: What does the HTML template look like? have you provided any logic such as if statements?  I think this may be where your solution lies..

Comment: the HTML template it doesn't matter, the issue is that the information that I need regarding the relation between parent and children and depth level of the category it is not sent to the template. I need to overwrite the default Field allocated by the ManyToMany . I'm referring to the 'internal' Field ModelSelectMultiple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django allows you to define the model you are referencing in a `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` as an `'<app_name>.<model_name>'` string instead of having to import the model and directly assigning it. This resolves a lot of issues, especially circular imports.

---

Assuming you have the apps `categories` with a `Category` model and `products` with a `Product` model, this:

`products/models.py`:

```
class Product:
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

`categories/models.py`:

```
class Category:
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(self)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

can directly translate to what you need:

`products/models.py`:

```
class Product:
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('categories.Category')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

`categories/models.py`:

```
class Category:
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

With this, you can have as many categories as you want:

```
category_one = Category.create(name='Category one')
category_two = Category.create(name='Category two')
category_three = Category.create(name='Category three')
category_three.categories.add(category_one, category_two)
some_product = Product.create(name='Test Product')
some_product.categories.add(category_three)
```

([ManyToManyField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/))

---

It is also important to note that with any Python class, `self` isn't the class itself – it's the instance. So you can't reference it outside of an instance method, there's a good explanation on why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987018/why-does-self-outside-a-functions-parameters-give-a-not-defined-error). The only reason the `'self'` string works here is because Django translates that to the class it's within, `categories.Category` –– so it might be a good idea to replace `self` with `'categories.Category'` to be explicit.

Comment: I understand what Django is doing, this is not the issue, I need to overwrite the default 'internal' Field selected by Django for ManytoMany and also create a custom widget